# GeoServer map layers/tiles Loaded in the screen or Not

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver, wms

I'm using OpenLayers - 2.11,GeoServer 2.13, ExtJS 3.4, and Java for developing GIS based web applications.
Please guide me to check if all my GeoServer map layers/tiles Loaded in the screen or not.
While dragging map is taking time to load next tiles. So that time i want to mask all the map body and unmask after loading all the map tiles.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open the below link for getting Answer for the Above Question :)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74061/geoserver-map-layers-tiles-loaded-in-the-screen-or-not/74069?noredirect=1#comment101451_74069